# Question regarding the inductive hypothesis of $k \geq 1$ step in a mathematical deduction example

Tags: discrete-mathematics

I am now starting to learn about mathematical deductions in discrete mathematics. In the first example I have to prove that $\forall n \geq 1, \sum_{i=1}^{n}i= \frac{ n (n+1) }{2}$. For the base case, we take $i=1$ and we have $1=1$ which it true. For the next step, my textbook states that taking a $k \geq 1$ we assume the statement is true. However shouldn't $k$ be bigger that 1 strctly, as we already know that it is true for $k=1$? If $k=1$ then we just know that the base case is true, which is something we have already proved to be correct. To move up the "ladder", to the inductive hypothesis and then the conclusion, shouldn't we take $k \geq 1$?  Can anyone explain?

Comment: Can you please tidy up the question? $k\ge 1$ means that $k$ *is* strictly positive, there is no apparent contradiction. Possibly you have a typo somewhere... Did they assume the statement was true for $k$ and then proved it for $k+1$, or did they assume the statement was true for $k-1$ and proved it for $k$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We need to assume the case for $n=k$ is true to prove the case $n=k+1$ is true.

Using this, we prove the case $n=2$ (and onwards) from the case $n=1$ (the base case).

Therefore $k$ must start from $1$.

On the contrary, suppose $k$ starts from $2$. Indeed we can build upon the assumption that the case for $n=2$ is true to establish the cases for $n>2$. However all our work would build upon that assumption, which has never been proven. With the base case $n=1$, we can show that the case $n=2$ is true, completing the argument.